# Kendo Multi Select with check boxes

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

Could you please let me know the steps how to implement the check box with kenod multi select and also after button click i have to retain the selected values. Can any one help me in acheiving this functionality.

Comment: Do you want to have checkboxes in list of items to select, in box contains selected items or both?

Comment: Check box in the list of items and have to retain after button click as well